# How can I check if a named range is in my current range?

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to name a range of cells.

So for example if A1 to B2 was named RangeA and I select A1 to C2, is there anyway I can tell if RangeA is inside of it?

Comment: look at `Application.Intersect()`

Comment: @TimWilliams I took the liberty of expanding your comment into an answer...

Comment: @TimWilliams this is awesome, I was more looking for if I didnt know about RangeA. Like view all named ranges in the selection. Sorry for being unclear. This will help me regardless.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code to help you on your way:

```
Sub test()
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, r3 As Range

Set r1 = Range("A1:A5")
Set r2 = Range("A3:A6")
Set r3 = Application.Intersect(r1, r2)

If Not r3 Is Nothing Then
  If r3.Cells.Count = r2.Cells.Count Then
    MsgBox "there is a complete intersection"
  Else
    MsgBox "there is some overlap"
  End If
Else
  MsgBox "there is no overlap"
End If

End Sub
```

Should be pretty self-explanatory. And with a tip of the hat to @TimWilliams who posted a comment along these lines.

**UPDATE** based on your clarification of requirement

```
Sub getIntersectingNames(r As Range)
  For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Not Application.Intersect(r, Range(Nm)) Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox Nm.Name & " intersects"
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Sub test()
  ' pop up a message box for every range that intersects cell B2:
  getIntersectingNames [B2]
End Sub

Function listIntersectingNames(r As Range)
  Dim result() As String
  ReDim result(1 To ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count)
  Dim matchCount As Integer

  matchCount = 0

  For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Not Application.Intersect(r, Range(Nm)) Is Nothing Then
      matchCount = matchCount + 1
      result(matchCount) = Nm.Name
    End If
  Next
  ReDim Preserve result(1 To matchCount)
  listIntersectingNames = result

End Function

Sub test2()
' return an array of names of all ranges that intersect cell B3:
  ans = listIntersectingNames([B3])
  s = ""
  For Each r In ans
    s = s & r & vbCrLf
  Next
  MsgBox s
End Sub
```

I don't know quite how you want to "return a list of names", so I give a couple of options in the above. Let me know if you can apply this to your situation or if you need more?

Comment: thanks. This is really close to what I want to do. I really wanted if you could get a list of all named ranges in your current selection. Without knowing about the other ranges.

Comment: @elb0w - updated answer based on your updated request.

Answer (score 1):

Further expanding what Tim and Floris said, see below:

```
Dim myNamedRange As Range, mySelection As Range, myIntersect As Range

Set mySelection = Selection '~~> gets your selection
Set myNamedRange = Range("RangeA") '~~> can be declared or directly pass to Intersect
Set myIntersect = Intersect(mySelection, myNamedRange)

    '~~> Then use intersect
If Not myIntersect Is Nothing Then
    If myIntersect.Address = myNamedRange.Address Then
        MsgBox "Your named range is within your selection."
    Else
        MsgBox "Your named range is beyond your selection."
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Your named range is beyond your selection."
End If

End Sub
```

This is based on your actual question having a named range `RangeA` to be compared with a selection.
Hope this helps a bit.